# Selecting rows which more than one second different from each other MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

This is a view from my table where i only selected the DateTime and id.
What i am looking for i a query that only shows records which aren't within an ID range of 5 of each other. Or which are more than a second different from each other.

```
---------------------+--------+
| DateTime            | id     |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2018-06-02 16:10:13 |  61863 |
| 2018-06-03 14:04:13 |  63715 |
| 2018-06-03 17:34:28 |  64339 |
| 2018-06-04 14:20:55 |  67227 |
| 2018-06-04 14:20:56 |  67228 |
| 2018-06-04 15:39:47 |  67845 |
| 2018-06-04 17:07:12 |  68085 |
| 2018-06-04 17:07:13 |  68086 |
| 2018-06-04 17:51:11 |  68197 |
| 2018-06-04 17:51:12 |  68199 |
| 2018-06-05 05:22:59 |  68518 |
| 2018-06-05 05:23:00 |  68519 |
| 2018-06-07 10:28:28 |  74568 |
| 2018-06-07 16:18:36 |  76386 |
```

so my table would look like this:

```
---------------------+--------+
| DateTime            | id     |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2018-06-02 16:10:13 |  61863 |
| 2018-06-03 14:04:13 |  63715 |
| 2018-06-03 17:34:28 |  64339 |
| 2018-06-04 14:20:55 |  67227 |
| 2018-06-04 15:39:47 |  67845 |
| 2018-06-04 17:07:12 |  68085 |
| 2018-06-04 17:51:11 |  68197 |
| 2018-06-05 05:22:59 |  68518 |
| 2018-06-07 10:28:28 |  74568 |
| 2018-06-07 16:18:36 |  76386 |
```

It doesn't matter if `2018-06-04 14:20:55` or if `2018-06-04 14:20:56` gets shown in the query. Same goes for the rest, as long as it's one of them

I've tried this query but it only works if the ID's are contiginous

```
 SELECT t0.*, t1.id
 FROM table t0
 LEFT JOIN table t1
 ON t0.id + 1 = t1.id
    WHERE t1.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: "It doesn't matter which row is shown, as long as at least of them is not shown."  This sentence makes no sense to me.

Comment: I think I've made it more clear with an example

Comment: What if you have 1-4-7?  Do you want 1 and 7?  Or only 1?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but look at it this way: assume that when there is only 1 second different they are duplicate and i want to remove the duplicates and it doesn't matter which one gets removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourdata t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourdata x
    WHERE (x.DateTime > t.DateTime AND x.DateTime <= t.DateTime + INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
    OR    (x.id       > t.id       AND x.id       <= t.id + 4)
)
```

Rows with same datetime or id are NOT counted.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.Datetime, t1.id
from mytable t1
join mytable t2
on t2.Datetime=(select Datetime from mytable t2 
where t2.Datetime > t1.Datetime 
and t2.id-t1.id > 5
limit 1)
where timestampdiff(second,t1.Datetime,t2.Datetime)>1;
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks you so much, i've been trying multiple variations on mine, also with the DateTime > INTERVAL 1 second and stuff. But this one is great.